# Find and Replace Value in Specific Column in excel using python

Tags: python

Hi new python learner here, currently I’m working on my project called ReplaceCode10to0 I just want to replace code number 10 changed into 0 in Column A only. There’s a lot of mixing number from 1-10, all I need to do is replaced the 10 code into 0 my excel file was CSV.

Thanks in advance

I tried some different codes but all of the codes from 1-10 were changed into 0

Comment: Do you have an Excel spreadsheet or a CSV file? Your question is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can read CSV file as String successfully and using the pure Python code, no other library. I will use `re` built-in package for regular expression.

For the column A, we use `^` which represents beginning of the line. `re.sub` is the substitute function.

- The first param is regular expression pattern.
- The second param is the string to replace.
- The third param is the input string.

We use `,` in the pattern to replace exactly `10`, not `100`.

```
import re


result = re.sub(r'^10,', '0,', your_input_line)
```

example:

```
>>> line = "10,asdf"
>>> re.sub(r"^10,", "0,", line)
'0,asdf'
```